# How to compile boost 1.54 with msvc10 and ICU?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, icu, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make my first application in unicode, and I understand why there is still so much applications that fail dealing with that.
I rode few articles that suggested to use utf-8 (and std::string) as much as possible. I need to be cross plateforms, and I actually try to deal with Windows.
Since I need a lot of regex, and I found boost really usefull, I'm trying to compile it with ICU, but I spent my whole day failing.
I'm so wondering if someone already successed to compile boost (1.54) with msvc10.0 using ICU (5.2) ?

I tried all bjam combinations (trying first to compile locale) without any success, and became a little esoteric like :

```
>.\bjam --with-locale -sHAVE_ICU=1 -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> stage
>.\bjam --with-locale -sHAVE_ICU=1 -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> -a stage
>.\bjam --with-locale -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> stage
>.\bjam --with-locale -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> -a stage
>.\bjam --with-locale stage
>.\bjam --with-locale -a stage
>.\bjam --with-locale -sHAVE_ICU=1 -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> install
>.\bjam --with-locale -sHAVE_ICU=1 -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> -a install
>.\bjam --with-locale -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> install
>.\bjam --with-locale -sICU_PATH=<ICU_path> -a install
>.\bjam --with-locale install
>.\bjam --with-locale -a install
...
```

As you can see, I'm not really familiar with boost.
I rode few people complaining about trying the same, but on older versions, and theirs solutions doesn't work with me.
I noticed that ICU binaries aren't distributed with debug libraries, so I compiled ICU by my own, but that didn't solve anything (and I tried too using bjam with only the release variant).

I also tried to compile using the mak file (vc10.mak in booste locale folder) but it generated me 1.53 versions of libs. I thought that was juste a mistake in the mak file, so I just tried to recompile after replacing every 1.53 by 1.54 in the mak file, but nothing to do, "has_icu builds" still tell me "no (cached)", and my application using some ICU stuffs still failed to link.

I'm still a beginner with boost, and with all that Unicode stuffs, but did I miss something or it is impossible to compile the latest version of boost with ICU ? Moreover, I can't find any error report/log from boost.

Thanks for your help !

Kallys

Answer (score 1):

Seems like today is a better day and my application now compile & link successfully with boost 1.54 and ICU.
Finally that was my fault, such a dumb stuff, but if someone have the same problem, and come to this topic, I just suggest two things : compile your own ICU (binaries don't provide debug which are needed to boost) and run the icucheck.bat to test your binaries, in both variants.

Personnally, I only checked the debug variant. My release icu binary compiled and linked without any arror, but when I checked today, it failed the test. Just a clean and a rebuild, and everything works perfectly.